# Userform get Username and password and use it in macro

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am using Excel 2013 and am new to using userforms. I have created a Userform with textbox for Username, Password and Datasource. I want to use these data in my macro. how to reference them? Secondly how to activate OK, Cancel button in the userform.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your userform is named "Userform1", and you text boxes are "Textbox1", "Textbox2", etc, you can use:

```
Userform1.TextBox1.Value
```

to retrieve the value of the first text box. Use the same for "Textbox2" and so on. Each other type of control can be referenced in the same manner.